# Simulated data for statistical framework testing

Tags: accuracy, synthetic-data

I want to generate two sets of simulated data (numeric) for statistical testing. Is it possible to generate datasets with predefined RMSE or accuracy?

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this by modeling some true relationship plus noise. The amount of noise will drive the accuracy of the model.

For instance, assume I want synthetic data where a linear regression model should have a RMSE of roughly 1. The following would achieve this goal:

$$
y_i = x_i + \epsilon_i,
$$

where $\epsilon_i\sim\mathcal{N}(0, 1)$.

```
set.seed(144)
x <- rnorm(10000)
y <- x + rnorm(10000)
mod <- lm(y~x)
sqrt(mean((predict(mod)-y)^2))
# [1] 0.9992113
```

Comment: Thats a wonderful idea. To be clear- if I have an existing dataset, I would use them as an independent variable (as in x) to generate the new one (y)- right?

Comment: @Msilvy sure -- you could pull the independent variables from some dataset you have and then simulate the outcome to be some function of the variables plus noise.

Comment: Thanks. That's really helpful. 
Another question- Can I put a constraint while generating x, such as max, min?

Comment: @Msilvy sure -- just sample from a distribution with a maximum and a minimum. For instance `x <- runif(10000, 3, 7)` in the code above would limit `x` to be between 3 and 7.